# Is it necessary to manually invalidate Facebook Access Token?

Tags: react-native, facebook-graph-api, expo, facebook-access-token, facebook-authentication

I'm building my first app using react-native and expo.

When I log in into my app using Facebook Auth and my personal account, I receive an access token; then I save it locally in the device using SecureStore, provided by expo.
If I try to log out, and then log in another time, I receive a new access token, different from the first one.
But if I try to make a get request, for example just to obtain the name of my facebook account, using the old access token...I can do it!

I wrongly thought that every time the same user try to access into the app using facebook auth, facebook gives the same access token given in the previous session (if it isn't expired or invalidated yet).

So... What I have to do? Just locally override the old token with the new token? Or should I invalidate the old token because of it is still valid (and if so, how could I do this)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access Tokens are not valid forever: Basic User and Page Tokens are valid for 2 hours so you do not have to invalidate them on your own. Extended Tokens are valid for 60 days but I assume you do not use those. Just override the Token with the new one, you do not need to worry about old Tokens.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#termtokens

Comment: It is an extended token because of I received it three days ago, and I used it to get my account's name yesterday. However, I will follow your advice, overriding the old token with the new one every time the user logs in into the app.